# Get all objects from foreign key

Tags: python, django

**models.py:**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    def all_shops(self):
        pass

class Town(models.Model):
    county =  models.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = models.CharField()

class Shop(models.Model):
    town = models.ForeignKey(Town)
    ...
```

**From Country object I need to view all shops in that country.** This is a light example, so, there are many models from country model to shop model (all have foreign keys). I want to tell, that use `town__county` in **Shop** model - bad practice, because in real situation there is many-many models and `filter()` will be very-very big.

if I use

```
return self.shops_set.all()
```

in `all_shops()` - this does not work.

For example, we have country with id = 1. How to get all shops in that country with described situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explain exactly what happens, rather than saying "this does not work".

However the call should be `self.shop_set.all()`.

**Edit** Sorry, I didn't realize you were going from Country to Shop. The correct call is `Shop.objects.filter(town__country=self).`

I have no idea what you mean by your comment that doing this would be bad practice.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Country' object has no attribute 'shop_set'

Comment: I mean that if we have many models with fk, we need to write very big filter()

Comment: I still don't follow. If you have many different model classes and you need to join them, then yes you will have to write a big statement. So what?

Comment: I am interesting, that is there a way not to write a big statement

Comment: Yes: don't have long chains of foreign keys.